# regexp_substr to picking up words similar to like condition with %

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I googled and can't find the solution for regexp_substr

```
select *
from customer
where lower (comment) like '%m%g';
```

in the comment can contain any sentence that might, imagine, migraine
The next step is trying to find picking up that word in new column

I want specific this word any related in %imm%g% or %im%g% in small or big or mixed letters as the output like immigrant, immigration, imigrant, immigration (yep it can be a typo), Immigration, IMMIGRATION

```
select a.*,
regexp_susbtr (comment, '.mmig+\w*|.mig+\w*') as selected
from customer a
where lower (comment) like %imm%g%'
or lower (comment) like %im%g%;
```

`regexp_susbtr (comment,'.mmig+\w*|.mig+\w*'`  <<<== only picking up small letters, what's proper coding that picking up any small, big or mix letters

`where regexp_like(comment, 'immig|imig','i')`  <<<== if I am right, this is similar to below, isn't?

```
where lower (comment) like %immig%'
or lower (comment) like %imig%;
```

next other question;

what's an alternative way for `%` to replace to finding any alphabets between `m` and `g` for `regexp_substr` and `regexp_like`

I am using ORACLE SQL and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```sql
> select a.*,
>        regexp_susbtr (comment, '.mmig+\w*|.mig+\w*') as selected
> from   customer a
> where  lower (comment) like %imm%g%'
> or     lower (comment) like %im%g%;
> ```
>
> `regexp_susbtr (comment,'.mmig+\w*|.mig+\w*'` <<<== only picking up small letters, what's proper coding that picking up any small, big or mix letters

Refer to the [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099)

> #### Syntax
>
> [image: Syntax diagram for REGEXP_SUBSTR]

...

And the `match_param` argument is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_COUNT.html#GUID-5148AF2E-9CED-497D-A78D-3A7847A45276) as:

> - `match_param` is a character expression of the data type `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` that lets you change the default matching behavior of the function.
>
>   The value of match_param can include one or more of the following characters:
>
>   - `'i'` specifies case-insensitive matching, even if the determined collation of the condition is case-sensitive.

So you want:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment, '\w*mig\w*', 1, 1, 'i') AS selected
FROM   customer a
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(comment, 'im\w*?g', 'i');
```

Where:

- `\w*mig\w*` will match zero-or-more (as many as possible) word characters then the sub-string `mig` and then zero-or-more (as many as possible) word characters and the `'i'` match parameter makes the match case insensitive.
- `'im\w*?g'` matches the sub-string `im` then zero-or-more word characters (as few as possible) and then the `g` sub-string and the `'i'` match parameter makes the match case insensitive.

> what's an alternative way for `%` to replace to finding any alphabets between `m` and `g` for `regexp_substr` and `regexp_like`

If you want word characters `a` to `z` and `0` to `9` in any case and `_` underscore then use the PERL-like `\w` pattern.

If you just want alphabetic characters then use the POSIX character class `[[:alpha:]]` or `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-z]` with case insensitive matching.

So for just alphabetic characters:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment, '[[:alpha:]]*mig[[:alpha:]]*', 1, 1, 'i') AS selected
FROM   customer a
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(comment, 'im[[:alpha:]]*?g', 'i');
```

or:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment, '[a-z]*mig[a-z]*', 1, 1, 'i') AS selected
FROM   customer a
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(comment, 'im[a-z]*?g', 'i');
```

Comment: hi @MTO, can I ask how to pick up a word to focus on 'anti'? it comes up varied such as quantity, substantial, significant if using ' \w * anti \w * '  
Tried using  this (sorry about extra space in this comment to avoid weird show fonts here)  ' ^ anti\w*'  didn't work that way, appreciated your help again

Comment: @Lizzie you could use `(^|\W)(anti\w*)` if you want `anti` at the start of a word (you would need to match the preceding non-word character, or the start of the string, as Oracle does not support zero-width look-behinds).

Answer (score 0):

This is one option; see if it helps.

Some sample data:

```
SQL> with customer (col) as
  2    (select 'I am not an immigrant'                         from dual union all
  3     select 'I want immigration to be found'                from dual union all
  4     select 'Who is "imigrant"?'                            from dual union all
  5     select 'Yep, that is immigration we are talking about' from dual union all
  6     select 'What? IMMIGRATION on TV?'                      from dual union all
  7     select 'Imagine all the people'                        from dual union all
  8     select 'Awful migraine in my head'                     from dual union all
  9     select 'No such word here'                             from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select col,
 12    regexp_substr(col, 'im.*g\w+', 1, 1, 'i') result
 13  from customer
 14  where lower(col) like '%im%g%';

COL                                           RESULT
--------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
I am not an immigrant                         immigrant
I want immigration to be found                immigration
Who is "imigrant"?                            imigrant
Yep, that is immigration we are talking about immigration
What? IMMIGRATION on TV?                      IMMIGRATION
Imagine all the people                        Imagine

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you so much @Littlefoot!!!
I tried that similar at past which it shows up whole sentences after immigration for an example scenario, 'I am not an immigrant b*gger off', my output result like 'immigrant b*gger', and some words that I playing around to add extra words on your an example some of them work and didn't work.... thank you for your help again

Comment: You're welcome.